# Grails render view with objects from other domains

Tags: grails

What I have is two, related domain objects.

First is:

```
class VideoCategory {

    String videoCategoryName

    static constraints = {
        videoCategoryName nullable: false
    }
}
```

Then I have:

```
class Video {

    VideoCategory videoCategory
    String fileName
    String videoTitle
    String videoDescription

    static constraints = {
        fileName nullable: false
        videoTitle nullable: true
        videoDescription nullable: true
    }
}
```

What I want is a create page for Video that will show not the videoCategoryId from the VideoCategory object, but the videoCategoryName itself in the scaffold dropdown.  I want to use the id as a FK, but render the name...then upon save I want to save the id instead.  I'm pretty new to Java/Groovy ways of thinking.  In python/flask I might just ensure that the objects are all imported in my views and then I can call them directly and `render_view` with that data and then embed the `id` as the value for saving while render the videoCategoryName value in the markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to VideoCategory class:

```
String toString() {
    return videoCategoryName
}
```